# Service dying, seeing "ActivityManager: Timeout executing service..." in logs. Cause?

Tags: android

Under what specific circumstances does such a timeout occur? I schedule an alarm to start a service at regular intervals, so I create a PendingIntent that targets the service (by calling PendingIntent.getService(......)), and pass it to the AlarmManager setRepeating(.....) method. The alarm type is RTC_WAKEUP.

As currently implemented the service does not spawn a separate thread to do its work, doing it all in onStart().

The service does some DB queries, and I suspect the reason I now regularly see "Timeout executing service.." messages for the service in the logs, as my service dies, has to do with these queries taking longer as the DB increases in size.

What *specifically*, though, causes the execution timeout.

- Is it doing the work on the **main** thread?

So, spawning a separate thread from onStart() that allows onStart() to return in a timely fashion, while the DB queries etc. run on the separate thread would completely eliminate the issue? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using android.app.Service as the base class, you're doing the work on the main thread. Developers, please do *not* do DB operations on the main thread! You'll slow down the system and most likely cause an ANR for your app.

Use IntentService instead of Service to ensure the work happens on a separate thread. IntentService is specifically designed to do asynchronous background processing on a separate thread.

You can set up AlarmManager in the IntentService itself, and then have it automatically repeat without intervention from your app. Send a "start" intent to the IntentService to start the Service the first time and set up the repeating schedule. Give a "cycle" intent to a PendingIntent and then use AlarmManager.setRepeating to set your schedule. On a regular basis, the AlarmManager instance will send the "cycle" intent to your IntentService, and in it you can do your DB work.

To stop the alarm, have a "stop" intent you can send that will cancel the alarm.

Comment: And in 2019, use `JobScheduler` / `JobIntentService`.